# How to use async await in lodash find method?

Tags: javascript, async-await, lodash

I am using await in find. Even If  if `(item  && isInputEnabled)` is `false`, find method is returning a matching item from the array

```
const isTravelerActiveChannelVac = !!find(array, async (item) => {
  const isInputEnabled = await someFunction();
  if (item && isInputEnabled) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: `lodash.find()` doesn't support promises.

Comment: neither does native Array find

Comment: but lodash map support

Answer (score 2):

The `find` function returns the first element that the callback function returns a truthy value for.

`async` functions return Promises.

Promises are truthy.

Therefore, you can't do it directly.

---

You could get the answers in an array and then find the one you want.

```
const promises = array.map(item = {
    const isInputEnabled = await someFunction();
    return { item, isInputEnabled };
});
const data = await Promise.all(promises);
const isTravelerActiveChannelVac = !!find(data, item => item.isInputEnabled);
```

But this calls `someFunction` for every item in the array and not just for those up to the one that matches.

---

You could use a `for` loop instead.

```
const findActiveChannelVac = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        const item = array(i);
        const isInputEnabled = await someFunction();
        if (item && isInputEnabled) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Can we use promises in Array.some ?

Comment: No. Array.some also cares if the returned value is truthy or not.